# Hysteresis thresholding in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

I am working currently on an Canny edge detector implementation in Python.

The problem I have is with an efficient array manipulation. To make it easier for Python people I wrote the same thing I need in matlab just for sake of the algorithm. At the end there is a commented matlab code to explain it. Before I would like to show my Python code that i wrote until now and explain what I need. My code is working but the problem is speed:

I have a picture as an np.array. I need to implement this:

There are two thresholds. High and low. I need to find all elements that are >high, all elements that are connected to high ones(vertically, horizontally and diagonally) and are between those two thresholds. Elements below low are discarded. Also elements that are between two thresholds but not connected in any way to elements above high should be discarded. By connected I mean connected even over other elements that form edges(chains).
In Python as I could see until now I should take the opposite route from one in Matlab. That means first find all elements above low. The reason for this is if I first find elements > high I just don't see a way how to keep connections.(For this to work I would need the possibility to call cv2.connectedComponents on specific rows and columns of a np.array but then I dont get a matrix of the same size). So with that being said, find all connected elements to those above low. In those connected groups check if there is an element above high. If not set all to zero. My problem here is speed. I would like to know how could my for loop be replaced with one or two lines of code like I wrote it in matlab

```
def hyst_thresh(edge_img: np.array, high_thresh: float, low_thresh: float)

matrix = np.zeros(edge_img.shape) #create an empty matrix 

r, c = np.where(edge_img > low_thresh) # find positions of all elements that are above low threshold

matrix[r, c] = 1

r, c = np.where(edge_img > h_thresh) # find positions of all elements that are above high threshold

label, neighbors = cv2.connectedComponents(matrix.astype(np.uint8)) ## this gives me label which is number of groups(labels of groups) and a matrix neighbors

#Example: 
#
#label = 4(group 0, group 1 group 2 group 3)
#
#neighbors
#
#0 0 0 1 0
#0 1 1 1 0
#0 0 0 0 0
#2 2 2 0 3 
    
for i in range(1, label):
        y, z = np.where(neighbours == i)
        k1 = np.isin(r, y)
        k2 = np.isin(c,z)
        if not any(k1*k2):
            matrix[y, z] = 0
```

Matlab equivalent which does the same thing but in the opposite direction

```
function edges = hyst_thresh(edges_in, low, high)

  edges = zeros(size(edges_in)); % creating zero matrix
  
  %This returns two vectors r and c which contain row and column of elements that satisfy
   %the condition  
   [r, c] = find(edges_in > high);  
   

  % Next line finds all matrix elements that are connected to elements given by r and c. Return is a 
   %binray matrix 
  bw = bwselect(edges_in, c, r, 8); 

  %Next line sets all elements of my empty matrix on positions where bw is non zero to 1
  edges(find(bw)) = 1;

  %At this point I have extracted values that are above high threshold and all other values that are
   %connected to them. Those positions are now ones in my empty zero matrix from the beginning.

  %This last line finally should check if between those values are some values that are below the lower 
  %threshold. In order to do that, values on all positions from my input matrix that are below are set to 
  % zero. This way if there are some elements that were connected but have a low value will be discarded 
  % in my binary matrix 
  edges(find(edges_in < low)) = 0;
end
```